# Windows7 won't boot after upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I've recently upgraded ubuntu to 16.04 and my working dual-boot installation doesn't work anymore. Ubuntu loads fine, but Win7(loader) stops at blinking cursor on black screen. I've tried a few solutions, e.g. Boot-repair. There were obviously some issues during repair, which I don't understand.

I have two separate 500GB disks and Windows installation is present and OK, because ubuntu is recognizing it as connected medium.

This is what boot-repair advised me to post: http://paste2.org/GvYJpMWe

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Grub, or this forum, may not be the best resource for fixing Windows.  https://superuser.com/ can give better support for repairing Windows.  From the content of your message it appears Grub is working fine and giving you the option to boot to an `OS` that appears to be broken.

You could boot to the Window's install media and use their repair option which would most likely destroy grub, but bring back your Windows.  After you have Windows working again, reinstall grub.

Reinstalling Grub is a simple five step process:

```
1) boot to the Ubuntu installation disk
2) Run the "Try Ubuntu" option
3) Bring up a terminal (Launch search "terminal")
4) Run these commands (exactly):
    a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt  # Make "X" the partition that has Ubuntu installed (i.e. /dev/sda2).
    b) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
    c) sudo chroot /mnt
    d) update-grub
    e) grub-install /dev/sdX (X is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
5) Reboot the system
```

Answer (score 0):

To repair dual boot issue you need to boot with ubuntu 16.04 installation disk and run this command on terminal:

```
grub2-mkconfig
```

If all went well, you should now be able to reboot into windows.